# Documentation content overlapping with sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

There is an alignment issue in the [SQL Example Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/280/example-databases#t=201607211242070402199) topic. The content is overlapped with the side bar.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Alignment issue]