# Documentation icon is visible in preview, but not in the actual post

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design

In Stack Overflow Meta, the documentation icon is visible in the preview, but the same is not visible in the actual post.

For example, in [this question's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328475/2451726) preview mode the icon is visible, but in the actual post the icon is not visible.

> [image: Documentation icon issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough, we weren't checking meta sites for Documentation links. From now on, we will (assuming the parent site has Documentation enabled).

This fix is unfortunately not retroactive since we save baked HTML, but editing any affected post will trigger a re-bake and style the links correctly.